# Appending data to executable to avoid triggering anti-virus software on Windows

Tags: windows, file, exe, executable, portable-executable

My understanding is that the Windows PE executable file format has specific areas for data.

Currently, I am appending data to an executable, and it quickly declares it as being a virus in quite a few different anti-virus programs.  It's at the point where any produced EXE triggers it.

Besides constantly sending false positive notes to vendors, is there a more appropriate method for appending data to an executable on Windows without being limited by data size?

Comment: Save it in the same directory as the exe rather than IN the exe

Comment: Not an option, unfortunately.  I'd like users to download a single installation file.  Not multiple.

Comment: Then I'd suggest creating an MSI, using a ZIP or an exe based installer engine such as null softs.

Comment: I'm trying to do something automated.  So my users can build their own installations.  I actually am using NSIS for part of it already.

Comment: Just appending data to an executable should not get it flagged. Are you manually modifying stuff in the pe header? Like adding a section for your data?

Comment: Compile the data as custom resources into your executable image. That's what resources are for. If you think it is a good idea to have a huge executable image mapped into a process' address space, that is.

Comment: @IInspectable Mind making that into an answer and elaborating on the procedure so I can accept it?

Comment: @typ1232 I am not, no.